# Flutter 2.5.1 - Could not build the application for the simulator

Tags: flutter, dart, dart-null-safety

I migrated my project from Flutter 1 to 2.5.1, and I countered this error

**Result:**

```
In file included from
/Users/Jeremy/Developer/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/url_launcher-6.0.11/ios/Classes/FLT
URLLauncherPlugin.m:7:
/Users/Jeremy/Developer/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/url_launcher-6.0.11/ios/Classes/FLT
URLLauncherPlugin.h:5:9: fatal error: 'Flutter/Flutter.h' file not found

#import <Flutter/Flutter.h>
        ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

1 error generated.
note: Using new build system
note: Building targets in parallel
note: Planning build
note: Analyzing workspace
note: Constructing build description
note: Build preparation complete
note: Removed stale file
'/Users/Jeremy/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-bkrpcbgqxwmjkngadaeegdgrlbut/Build/Products/
Debug-iphonesimulator/share/share.framework'

note: Removed stale file
'/Users/Jeremy/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-bkrpcbgqxwmjkngadaeegdgrlbut/Build/Products/
Debug-iphonesimulator/flutter_keyboard_visibility/flutter_keyboard_visibility.framework'

note: Removed stale file
'/Users/Jeremy/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-bkrpcbgqxwmjkngadaeegdgrlbut/Build/Products/
Debug-iphonesimulator/sqflite/sqflite.framework'

note: Removed stale file
'/Users/Jeremy/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-bkrpcbgqxwmjkngadaeegdgrlbut/Build/Products/
Debug-iphonesimulator/geocoding/geocoding.framework'

note: Removed stale file
'/Users/Jeremy/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-bkrpcbgqxwmjkngadaeegdgrlbut/Build/Products/
Debug-iphonesimulator/package_info_plus/package_info_plus.framework'

note: Removed stale file
'/Users/Jeremy/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-bkrpcbgqxwmjkngadaeegdgrlbut/Build/Products/
Debug-iphonesimulator/google_sign_in/google_sign_in.framework'

note: Removed stale file
'/Users/Jeremy/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-bkrpcbgqxwmjkngadaeegdgrlbut/Build/Products/
Debug-iphonesimulator/connectivity_plus/connectivity_plus.framework'

note: Removed stale file
'/Users/Jeremy/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-bkrpcbgqxwmjkngadaeegdgrlbut/Build/Products/
Debug-iphonesimulator/Runner.app'

note: Removed stale file
'/Users/Jeremy/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-bkrpcbgqxwmjkngadaeegdgrlbut/Build/Products/
Debug-iphonesimulator/geolocator_apple/geolocator_apple.framework'

note: Removed stale file
'/Users/Jeremy/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-bkrpcbgqxwmjkngadaeegdgrlbut/Build/Products/
Debug-iphonesimulator/google_maps_flutter/google_maps_flutter.framework'
```

All of my package/plugins are updated to nullsafety version, and I also did delete the ios folder and created a new one using `flutter create .` and i still get the same result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many reasons why this error occurs since you've migrated to Flutter 2.0 (null-safety).

You re-created the whole `ios` and/or `android` which will generate the new codes (or syntax) and files which might lead to an error like what you're facing.

For anyone who are planning to migrate please always keep a backup file for your internal configs in `ios` and/or `android` folders respectively.

### ***DON'T JUST DROP YOUR `iOS` and `android` FOLDER BACK!***

You need to manually reconfig your files under those folders.
If you're using Firebase packages, you can add these lines in your Podfile inside the clause `target 'Runner'` do:

```
# add the Firebase pod for Google Analytics
# or pod ‘Firebase/AnalyticsWithoutAdIdSupport’
# for Analytics without IDFA collection capability
# add pods for any other desired Firebase products
# https://firebase.google.com/docs/ios/setup#available-pods
  pod 'Firebase/Analytics'
  pod 'Firebase/DynamicLinks'
```

Follow some tips [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EXp0gq9k%E2%80%A6)

After that, make sure that you configured back other app's metadata like `AppBundleName` and some permissions in `info.plist`

### ***ANOTHER THING***

*(might be optional)*
If you're gonna check the *pubspec.yaml*, there's a new line there which you need to add for new linting options. Pay attention to the spacing.

```
dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter
  flutter_lints: ^1.0.0
```

Then do what 99% `stackoverflow` users always says with this matter :)

> `delete pubspec.lock`

> `delete pods folder`

> `delete Podfile.lock`

> `flutter pub cache repair`

> `flutter clean`

> `flutter pub get`

Answer (score 0):

Remove the plugin from the `pubspec.yaml` and run `flutter pub get`.

Then add the plugin again and run `flutter pub get`.

or

`flutter pub cache repair`

Comment: Thank you for your answer, what do you mean remove the plugin?

Comment: should I remove all, or only the listed in the error?

Comment: Only the listed. `url_launcher`

Comment: I still get the same result.

Comment: try `flutter clean` and then `flutter pub get`

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/4XpLnyx i now get this result.

Answer (score 0):

Please Try this steps :

**if you have intel chip**

1. flutter clean
2. update all dependencies to the latest version in pubspec.yml file and do 'get pub'
3. Go to your Podfile and uncomment #platform :ios, '9.0' Then change the version to 10 platform :ios, '10.0'
4. go to ios folder throuh terminal and do 'pod repo update'
5. 'pod update' or 'pod install'

**if you have M1 chip**

1. flutter clean
2. update all dependencies to the latest version in pubspec.yml file and do 'get pub'
3. Go to your Podfile and uncomment #platform :ios, '9.0' Then change the version to 10 platform :ios, '10.0'
4. go to ios folder throuh terminal and do 'arch -x86_64 pod repo update'
5. 'arch -x86_64 pod update' or 'arch -x86_64 pod install'